# Redux does not redraw if store value is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux

1. Click the login button
2. Auth's action is called
3. Reducer called
4. Connect mapDispatchToProps is called
5. However, it is not redrawn

I am in trouble because the render method of React.Component 5 is not called and redrawing is not executed.

After reading this article, I think that using Render.Component's Object.assign should call Render of React.Component.

But it does not work.
Where is wrong?

---

**app.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import App from '../components/app'

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {login: state.login}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        dispatch
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**components/app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { auth } from '../actions/auth'
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="columns is-gapless">
                <div className="column is-10 content">
                    <div className="content-body">
                        <div className="has-text-right">
                            {(this.props.login)?"TRUE":"FALSE"}
                            <button className="button is-primary" onClick={()=>dispatch(auth("test@test.com","aaaa"))}>login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**actions/auth.js**

```
import {constant} from './constant';
export function auth(email,password) {
    return {
        type: constant.ACTION.AUTH,
        email: email,
        password:password
    }
}
```

**reducer**

```
import {constant} from './actions/constant';
const initialState = {
    login: false
};

export default function reducersIndex(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log("reducers");
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case constant.ACTION.AUTH:
            return Object.assign({}, state,{
                login:!state.login
            });
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this.props look like if you log it from <App />?

Comment: Your `mapStateToProps` gives you `this.props.state` and you are checking for `this.props.login` which (at least by looking on that part of code pasted here) seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: update my code. I check the debugger of redux that the state has changed.but not re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Your state contains the property `login`, which is set in your reducer. In your component, you are also checking `this.props.login`.

However, in `mapStateToProps`, you are mapping `state.state` to the prop `state`, leaving `this.props.login === undefined`. For this reason, `{(this.props.login)?"TRUE":"FALSE"}` will always evaluate to `"FALSE"`.

To resolve this, map `login` from your state to the prop `login` in your container:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {login: state.login}
}
```

Comment: sorry.made a mistake.but The actual code is constant.ACTION.AUTH.  

I check the debugger of redux that the state has changed.but not re-render.

Comment: I edited my answer to fit the updated code. Give it a try!